# Very basic calculus question - do you think there's a typo?

Tags: calculus

I'm helping someone with their homework before they go back to A-Levels, and I came across the following question which I think is miswritten:

> Find the gradient at $x=1$ of the equation $y=3x^2-1$' which is obviously $6$

The follow-up question is:

> Hence find the equation of the line parallel to the tangent through the point $(-1,1)$'

I notice that the point $(-1,1)$ doesn't lie on the equation of the curve. Do you think this is a typo? And that they actually originally wanted us to find the gradient at $x=-1$.

The answer given as correct is $y=6x+7$.

Comment: Misplaced modifier? Maybe it means "find the equation of the line through the point $(-1,1)$, parallel to the tangent line at $x=-1$".

Comment: @Doug the slope of this line will be 6 and then use the point slope folmula using the initial conditions. It becomes 6x + 7.

Comment: If the question is correctly transcribed, it is very badly written, though one can guess at the intention. For example an **equation** does not have a gradient. And they should have nade it clear that they wanted the equation of the line through $(-1,1)$ that is parallel to the line tangent to the curve at the point with $x$-coordinate equal to $1$.

Comment: Do you see where I am coming from, and that perhaps it is at least poorly written rather than miswritten? I thought they were talking about the line parallel to the tangent that runs through (-1,1) but when they say tangent, they are referring to the tangent at x=1

Answer (score 10):

No, it is not a typo. They are correct.

You differentiated correctly.

$f(x)=3x^2-1$

$f'(x)=2(3x) -0(1)$ (The power rule)

$f'(x)=6x$

Thus $f'(1)=6(1)=6$

The gradient at $x=1$ is 6.
A line parallel to the tangent would by definition also have a gradient of 6.

This means that the parallel line would have an equation in the form: $$y=6x+c$$ where $c$ is a constant.

Now substitute the coordinates given:
$$1=6(-1)+c$$
$$c= 1-(-6) =7$$
Thus the parallel line would have an equation of
$$y=6x+7$$

Answer (score 3):

The tangent has slope $6$.  The line they want is parallel to the tangent, and goes through $(-1,1)$